# Clean up Python output display

Tags: python, tiff

I have the code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
titles = open("user1_titles.txt",'r')
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
print(dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)), file = open("user1_tf.csv",'a'))
```

But it gives me the following output:

```
{'00': 7.8987145343299883, '007': 9.6034626265684135, '01': 9.6034626265684135, '012': 9.197997518460248, '01273': 9.6034626265684135, '02': 9.6034626265684135, '020': 9.6034626265684135, '026514': 9.6034626265684135,... etc
```

I need the output to be:

```
00 7.8987145343299883
007 9.6034626265684135
etc.
```

**I am aiming to remove the curly brackets {} from the output and just have 2 columns of data; name and value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#module-pprint)  — a "Data pretty printer":

```
from pprint import pprint

d = {'00': 7.8987145343299883, '007': 9.6034626265684135, '01': 9.6034626265684135, '012': 9.197997518460248, '01273': 9.6034626265684135, '02': 9.6034626265684135, '020': 9.6034626265684135, '026514': 9.6034626265684135}
pprint(d)
```

output:

```
{'00': 7.898714534329988,
 '007': 9.603462626568414,
 '01': 9.603462626568414,
 '012': 9.197997518460248,
 '01273': 9.603462626568414,
 '02': 9.603462626568414,
 '020': 9.603462626568414,
 '026514': 9.603462626568414}
```

or a with a handcrafted solution using [`format`](https://pyformat.info/):

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print( '{:>6} {}'.format(key, value) )
```

result:

```
026514 9.603462626568414
   012 9.197997518460248
    01 9.603462626568414
    00 7.898714534329988
   020 9.603462626568414
   007 9.603462626568414
    02 9.603462626568414
 01273 9.603462626568414
```

Comment: I edited my answer which was confusing. To remove the brackets you have to use the for loop and the print statement. This way you can use the `format` function and then, for example, specify also the number of digits you want, the alignment... etc

Comment: thank you, this works! however, the output appears in 1 column in the csv file. What would i need to do to split the column into 2?

Comment: depending on what delimiter you want to use, try with a comma `print( '{}, {}'.format(key, value) )`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in following manner

```
for key,value in (dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)), file = open("user1_tf.csv",'a')).iteritems()::
    print key,value
```

or
you can collect the output for your first statement in some variable and then print it
like:

```
data = print(dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)), file = open("user1_tf.csv",'a'))
for key,value in data.iteritems():
    print key,value
```

Comment: I believe this only prints the keys, the OP also wants values.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as Saurabh's answer but prints values.

```
def splitPrint(data):
    for key,value in data.items():
        print(key, value)
```